# RadMenu Finding Items Recursively By Value on Client

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax

Using the ASP.NET AJAX controls of Telerik's, there is a method called `findItemByValue` on the menu that can find an item by its value.

But it only looks within the root level item apparently.

Is there a method in the client API that can find an item by value, but recursively without me having to manually loop through each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no `findItemByValue` method searching recursively, because of how the `RadMenu` is designed.

However, instead of "manually looping through each item", you can use the `get_allItems()` method.

```
function recursiveFindItemByValue(searchedValue)
{  
    var menu = $find("<%=RadMenu1.ClientID %>");  
    var menuItems = menu.get_allItems();

    for (var i=0; i< menuItems.length; i++)  
    {    
        if(menuItems[i].get_value()==searchedValue)
            return menuItems[i];
    }
}
```

If you really don't want to use a loop, you can search for a way to use the `get_contextMenuElement()` to get the DOM element for the `RadMenu`, and then use `getElementById` if you have an idea of what would the element's look like. (But I'd rather with the first solution..